# CountDownTimer on version 4.4.2 - 4.4.4 can not be cancelled

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have a CountDownTimer which works perfectly on every android version except 4.4.2 - 4.4.4. Does anyone know why this is happening? The way i am stopping the timer it is when it goes <= 0 .

```
    mTimerRemaining = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished) {

            mTimeRemainingNum -= 1000; 

            if(mTimeRemainingNum <= 0) {
                mTimerRemaining.cancel();
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {

         // On Finish doesn't work 
        }
    };

    mTimerRemaining.start();
```

Comment: Provide the code, please. The community will be able to assist you better.

Comment: What is the app doing on 4.4.2 - 4.4.4.  ?

Comment: @KevinLEGOFF i just found a bug on that version and trying to fix it

Comment: @Tony what is the bug ?? Is it that on finished is never called ?

Comment: No... we don't know what is happening.  If you were to tell us how it was failing, we might have a prayer of telling you why! ;-P

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike ok i found that the timer i was using..it was "endless" because it was taking a very big number to count until it goes to 0 or less. It doesn't really matter, because i stop the timer when some calculations happen..so even if the timer doesn't go below 0 it ends. That means, on every other android version the cancel() works great, but in this android version it doesn't.

Comment: Same problem here. I can confirm that cancel() doesn't work on CountDownTimer objects in Android 4.4.x.

Answer (score 1):

That is odd. Have you considered using a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) instead?

Example of use:

```
private final int interval = 10000; // 10 secs
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        // your code here
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);
```

Please, let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: yes..and i just tried it again, doesn't work. Please consider, it works perfectly on every other version of android the exactly way i have it.

Comment: Answer updated. Please, could you check it out again? If it solves your problem, could you upvote it and check it as the right answer, please? Thank you :)

Comment: It works thanks, but should i upvote it as an answer? It does my job, but i don't understand why my way doesn't work only in that version, what should i do?

Comment: You are right, it does not answer your doubt at all, just explain another way of doing the same thing. I didn't realize it until now. Please, don't check it as an answer. Let us wait for someone that knows why this bug occurs on such android versions. Cheers :)

Comment: This is now the correct answer.  Starting a new thread, just to mark time is not such a great idea

Answer (score 0):

Create a **CountDownTimer** class in your project

```
package your.package;

public abstract class CountDownTimer {

    private final android.os.CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

    private boolean isCancel = false;

    public CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        countDownTimer = new android.os.CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if (isCancel) {
                    return;
                }
                CountDownTimer.this.onTick(millisUntilFinished);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if (isCancel) {
                    return;
                }
                CountDownTimer.this.onFinish();
            }
        };
    }

    public final CountDownTimer start() {
        isCancel = false;
        countDownTimer.start();
        return this;
    }

    public final void cancel() {
        isCancel = true;
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    public abstract void onTick(long millisUntilFinished);

    public abstract void onFinish();
}
```

You just change the import from **android.os.CountDownTimer** to **your.package.CountDownTimer**

CountDownTimer class is Disposable.

Comment: 2. Can you provide some more explanation on what does your code do?

Comment: is so simple, after call cancel() The onTick function no longer runs